# How to use htaccess to rewrite only certain pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a small website I would like to rewrite only some pages with htaccess and hide index.php . I was tring this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ https%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^despre-noi/?$    despre-noi.php    [R=301,NC,L]    # Handle requests for "despre-noi"
RewriteRule    ^detalii-plati/?$    cum-platesc.php    [R=301,NC,L]    # Handle requests for "modalitati de plata"
RewriteRule    ^contact/?$    contact.php    [R=301,NC,L]    # Handle requests for "contact"
RewriteRule    ^politica-de-confidentialitate/?$    politica-de-confidentialitate.php    [R=301,NC,L]    # Handle requests for "politica de confidentialitate"
RewriteRule    ^termeni-si-conditii/?$    termeni-si-conditii.php    [R=301,NC,L]    # Handle requests for "termeni si conditii"


</ifModule>
```

The pages are loaded fine but is still showing the .php extension, but if I type in browser the URL without .php extension is whowing without extension. could you help to tell me where is wrong? Because I want only those pages to be in this condition, not the whole website.

Thank You

//Edit: I have ssl and for that is that condition with https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `[R=301]` from all of your `.php` rules  like

```
RewriteRule    ^despre-noi/?$    despre-noi.php    [NC,L]
```

---

Add the following slightly modified rule that you had used earlier for all php files.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(despre-noi|cum-platesc|contact)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

This needs to come before the `.php` file rules already in your htaccess. Add the names of all the php files you want to work this way inside the expression `(..|..)` for `%{THE_REQUEST}` condition.

---

> domain.com/contact.php to show it domain.com/contact-us

Yes, it's possible but since the names differ now, you'll have to remove `contact` from the current `%{THE_REQUEST}` rule's `(..|..)` entries and add a separate rule as follows (again before the `.php` rules)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /contact\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /contact-us [L,R=301]
```

Then just modify the existing `.php` rule as

```
RewriteRule    ^contact-us/?$    contact.php    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Still not working, like that I used the first time and I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: What happens when you open domain.com/contact?

Comment: When I type domain.com/contact In URL bar its show domain.com/contact but its open index.php. In the past I used    ``# match out the request URI without the trailing slash  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+?)/?$  
# and see if it exists  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.+?)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index  
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]``  but now I need to use it only for those pages, not for whole website. Thank You

Comment: @Thepliyal now it works, thank you for your support. What I want to ask you if you know how its possible to modify the name of url, I meen domain.com/contact.php to show it domain.com/contact-us . Anyway thank you again